# Eclipse Adding button in RunConfiguration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a button in my custom run configuration similar like `Show Command Line` in JavaApplication configuration.

[image]

What I have

```
 <extension
    point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTabGroups">
    <launchConfigurationTabGroup
        class="com.MyCustomTabGroup"
        id="com.configurationTabGroup"
        type="com.launch.configuration">
    </launchConfigurationTabGroup>
 </extension>
```

In `MyCustomTabGroup`, I defined the tabs which I have, but how to add a button next to  `Revert`, as same as `Show Command Line`

Comment: That row of buttons is created by an internal class `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer` and can't be modified.

Comment: And adding new button is also not possible?

Comment: You can't do anything with that row of buttons.